# VBS End of the statement expected error in

Tags: vbscript

```
strCode = "Private Sub AcclvsTime() " & vbCr _
 & "Set myChtObj = oExcelWriteWorkSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100,375,75,225) "& vbCr _
 & "myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = 4 " & vbCr _
 & "myChtObj.Chart.SetSourceData  objWriteWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:B15")" & vbCr _
& "End Sub"
objWriteExcel.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Item("Sheet1").CodeModule.AddFromString(strCode)
```

When I executed this code i got the error “end of the statement expected in line 4” (`& "myChtObj.Chart.SetSourceData  objWriteWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:B15")" & vbCr _`)

Can any one help me where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
" ... Range("A1:B15")" & vbCr
```

Note those quotes within quotes on your fourth line (for both `"sheet2"` and `"A1:B15"`) - you need to fix that.

If you want to put quotes within quotes, you can do it thus, by escaping. Two consecutive `"` characters within a double-quoted string will be translated to a single `"`.

```
"the word ""xyzzy"" is quoted"
```

Alternatively, you can also use `chr(34)` to get the quote:

```
"the word " & chr(34) & "xyzzy" & chr(34) & " is quoted"
```

This may be preferable in more complex cases, though I've rarely had a need for it.

Comment: please consider to remove the Chr(34) 'alternative', which has already claimed one victim (JanesDiary).

Comment: I see no indication that James has been a "victim" of that. I won't remove it because it is indeed an alternative, people can make up their own mind which way they want to go. I'd prefer to give them a fuller range of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

@paxdiablo: I would comment, but don't see a comment button.

Notice, though, the second quote from `Range("A1:B15")"` & vbCr is started from `"myChtObj.Chart.SetSourceData`

Having the full block of code would help better, as we can't tell what kind of end statement you will need. I.e, your `"End Sub"` is in double quotes. If that's the end of the sub, you need to take them out.

Comment: Tested Ekkehard.Horner code, and it does work. I also think that in correspondence with paxdiablo's statement about using `char(34)`, that would be better than using double quotes, which jumbles things up.

Comment: Using `& Chr(34) &` where `""` can be used is an errorprone malpractice.

Comment: I've never had much problems with it in the past, then again, i never did much with them anyway, were the teacher just wanted us to use them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Building strings by concatenation is cumbersome and errorprone. Especially, if the result is a multiline string, use Join:

```
strCode = Join( Array( _
        "Private Sub AcclvsTime()" _
      , "  Set myChtObj = oExcelWriteWorkSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100,375,75,225)" _
      , "  myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = 4" _
      , "  myChtObj.Chart.SetSourceData objWriteWorkbook.Sheets(""sheet2"").Range(""A1:B15"")" _
      , "End Sub" _
), vbCrLf)
WScript.Echo strCode
```

output:

```
Private Sub AcclvsTime()
  Set myChtObj = oExcelWriteWorkSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100,375,75,225)
  myChtObj.Chart.ChartType = 4
  myChtObj.Chart.SetSourceData objWriteWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:B15")
End Sub
```

to reduce the noise caused by `&` and the repeating stuff `vbCr(Lf)`. That will improve your chances to see the problems/mistakes. (Exactly **two** literals - "sheet2", "A1:B15" - to quote).

**Addional Remark:**

Given that the culprit is:

```
"whatever("sheet2").Range("A1:B15")"
```

it is obvious, that remedy

```
"whatever(""sheet2"").Range(""A1:B15"")"
```

is easier to read/check/write and less errorprone than

```
"whatever(" & Chr(24) & "sheet2" & Crh(34) & ").Range(" & Chr(34) + "A1:B15" & Chr(32) & ")"
```

Avoiding "" in literals by splicing in `& Chr(34) &`s is a **bad** strategy.